# Check whether the required field is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to check whether the required field  is  empty or not.
I used the code below.

```
$(":input").each(function() {
    if($(this).data('label')=='required')
     {
        if($(this).val() === "")
        alert("Empty Fields!!");
     }
});
```

But it was alert more than one time.
JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hbk2a5qo/3/

Answer (score 1):

Why not directly use `required` attribute in HTML:

```
<input id="name"type="text" data-label="required" required/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a flag

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        AlertSave();
    });
});

function AlertSave() {
    //use the flag to set the valid status in the loop
    var valid = true;
    //iterate over only the required elements
    $(':input[data-label="required"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (valid) {
        //do your save
    } else {
        alert("Empty Fields!!");
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2wL7zk4d/)

Comment: It works fine. and one more thing., If I had thousands of input fields and only 5 of them are required fields. It that case  `:input` is not possible. Is in it? Then how can I implement it?@Arun P Johny

Comment: why not? if you want better performance you can try something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2wL7zk4d/4/

Answer (score 0):

As you have used `$(":input").each()` so it will go through all fields. But you can use flag to show alert only once.

```
function AlertSave() {
var alertShown=false;   
    $(":input").each(function() {
        if($(this).data('label')=='required')
                        {
   if($(this).val() === "" && !alertShown)
   {
       alertShown=true;
        alert("Empty Fields!!");
   }
  }
});
    }
```

[You Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbk2a5qo/6/)

Answer (score 0):

By using `required` attribute (which is recommended), this will return all the required input fields that has no `value`:

```
var inputsWithMissingValues = $('input[required]').filter(function(i, input) {
  return !input.value.length;
});
```

So, if the length of that is more than zero, then you have required fields with missing value.